# Combining Variables results in "...does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'

Tags: powershell

This has been perplexing me for a few days. I am used to joining 2 variables together, e.g.

```
$a = "1"
$b = "2"
$c = $a + $b
```

Result: `$c = "12"`

I am trying to join 2 variables together, or combine the data in 2 variables which happens to be a table of data, each with multiple rows or entries, so I am left with one table. In my case I have 6 tables each with 20+ entries, which I want to combine into one consolidated list.

One of the columns in my data happens to be an array:

```
$d =
column1        : 123
column2        : 456    
column3        : 789
column4        : 012
column5        : {345}

column1        : 234
column2        : 457    
column3        : 890
column4        : 123
column5        : {}

$e = 
column1        : 987
column2        : 654    
column3        : 321
column4        : 098
column5        : {765,432}

column1        : 555
column2        : 444    
column3        : 333
column4        : 222
column5        : {111,222,333}

column1        : 666
column2        : 777    
column3        : 888
column4        : 999
column5        : {000}
```

The data structure is the same for each of my variables, i.e. same number and names of the columns.

I have tried many, many different ways to do this. Some of my share-worthy attempts are:

```
$f = $d + $e
```

fails with the error:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

I tried:

```
$f = $d | Select-Object -Property *
$f = $f + $e | Select-Object -Property *
```

That also results in the same error as above.

I tried experimenting with selecting the data into a hash-table(?)

```
$f = $d | Select-Object -Property @('*')
```

but again, this isn't getting me anywhere.

I tried exporting my variables to a CSV file with the -append option, thinking I could import it all back in again all nice and combined, but that was a disaster as the contents of the array was lost.

A few mentions on DuckDuckGo/StckOverflow for "does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'" however not for my particular case of combining tables together.

I am at a loss, for something that on the outset appeared to be a "simple" case of joining 2 variables together.

Comment: You can't just "add" arbitrary objects or data. PowerShell needs to know how that "addition" operation is supposed to happen, therefore it needs an implementation of the addition operator for the particular type. In case a type doesn't have that you get the error you observed.

Comment: If by "join 2 variables together" you mean "form an array of the 2 variables" you'd do that like this: `$f = @($d); $f += $e`, i.e. ensure you have an array, then append to that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Ansgar,

The answer that worked was in fact:

$f = @($d); $f += $e

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is caused by dynamic typing. As you don't tell Powershell what types of variables are used, it makes a wild guess. Since `1` and `2` are between double quotes, those are assumed to be strings instead of numbers. `+` for strings is interpreted as concatenation. For numeric types, it's addition.

When dealing with custom objects, addition is often ill-defined. For some types, there is default addition. This is the case for strings and arrays. For other types, there isn't sensible default available. This is expressed as familiar error message  *does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'*.

The proper way to combine your tables depends on their data types. As pseudocode, process like this could work:

```
create new table n
for each table t in your result set
    copy each row to nt from t
save nt
```